# How to make your Service-Reference proxy URL dynamic?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I have a web reference to web-service:

```
using (var client = new GetTemplateParamSoapClient("GetTemplateParamSoap"))
{
    TemplateParamsKeyValue[] responsArray = client.GetTemplatesParamsPerId(
        CtId, tempalteIds.ToArray());

    foreach (var pair in responsArray)
    {
        string value = FetchTemplateValue(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        TemplateComponentsData.Add(pair.Key, value);
    }
}
```

Tried to change a web-reference url from c# code: as advice here:

1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/wsdldynamicurl.aspx

2) [How to call a web service with a configurable URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571253/how-to-call-a-web-service-with-a-configurable-url-from-a-server-side-c-code)

3) http://aspalliance.com/283_Setting_Web_Service_References_Dynamically

But I get symbol is missing when trying to do:

```
client.Url
```

In addition I couldn't find a property of "Url_behavior"

Comment: This is because you don't have a Web Reference, you have a Service Reference. That's a good thing, but the way to set the Url is different.

Comment: How do I do it, then? I don't have an option on right click "add web-reference"

Comment: You don't want to use a web reference. Service Reference is the correct way to do it. I just don't have time to answer this morning. I'm sure someone will answer you shortly. In the meantime, maybe look at the different overloads of the constructor of your proxy class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a web service with a configurable url from a server side c# code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571253/how-to-call-a-web-service-with-a-configurable-url-from-a-server-side-c-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've already added the service reference, but here's a walkthrough on [adding, updating and removing service references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

Once you've got one of those in your project, you can alter the endpoint URI with one of the constructor overloads, as John Saunders said above.  To do this, you'll need to know the name of the **endpoint** in your config file.  For instance, after you add your service you might have elements like this in your config file:

```
<endpoint address="http://bleh.com/services/servicename.asmx"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceNameSoap"
    contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceNameSoap" name="ServiceNameSoap" />
```

Given that endpoint, you can change the `address` at runtime by using the following overload:

```
var proxy = new ServiceReference1.ServiceNameSoapClient("ServiceNameSoap",
    "http://new-address.com/services/servicename.asmx");
```

You can also do it after construction, but that becomes a little bit harder.  If you need to do so, see the documentation on the [Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553831%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property and the associated type [ServiceEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.aspx).