# Self Host WCF with Dynamic URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, model-view-controller

I am new to WCF, I am trying to create a WCF selfhost service with dynamic URL, which will be used to authentication user from client computer. this service will be installed in all client computers and web application should work if it finds this WCF service in client computer. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can implement self-hosted wcf,
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/137605/self-hosting-in-wcf/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/self-host

and then dynamically switch the wcf web service reference url path through the configuration file.
[How to make your Service-Reference proxy URL dynamic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571954/how-to-make-your-service-reference-proxy-url-dynamic)

[Dynamically switch WCF Web Service Reference URL path through config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036308/dynamically-switch-wcf-web-service-reference-url-path-through-config-file)

[How Dynamically change URL in a WCF Custom Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294111/how-dynamically-change-url-in-a-wcf-custom-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it possible to read from lan IP that is local IP of client system not the public IP

Comment: You can see if [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21155473/17218587) can help you.